# Flapping metrics in DC/OS dashboard after changing master nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper, coreos, mesosphere, dcos

After changing two of three master nodes in an DC/OS 1.8 cluster to a newer CoreOS version (one with a kernel that is patched against the DirtyCOW vulnerability) the masters stopped working. The dashboard showed an empty data center.

We synchronized /var/lib/dcos from the old master to the two new master nodes. Then the dashboard started working again. The DC/OS dashboard still shows flapping metrics.
We have a mesos.leader and a zookeeper leader.

How can we stabilize the cluster?

Comment: The DCOS cluster was launched with the official zen-3 CloudFormation template initially and the new masters use the same LaunchConfiguration , userdata (cloud-config) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time this happened to us we had to reinstall the cluster. I just finished stopping our master nodes one at a time to increase the disk size. We are now back in the flapping state. I think a reinstall is in our future. I'm searching for answers now to help avoid that.

Comment: Yes, we built a new cluster in the end. Even if your DC/OS cluster has autoscaling on private agent, public agent and at masters level. The group of masters is the most fragile part and you can't switch for example a group of three to newer operating systems here in a short time.